# Dynamic assignment of random images as button's background separately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

```
-(void)setButtons_AsPerTheMatrixSelection
{

        for(UIView *subview in [viewWithButtons subviews])
        {        
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    viewWithButtons = [[UIView alloc] init];

    width = 48;
    height = 48;

    pw = 49;
    ph = 49;

    arrButton = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImage *imgDefaultBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"];

    viewWithButtons.frame = CGRectMake(50, 40, 200, 260);

    ch = 4;
    cv = 4;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < cv ; ++i )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < ch ; ++j )
        {
            btnMatrix = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10+pw*j, 51+ph*i, width, height)] autorelease];
            btnMatrix.tag = i*ch+j;
            btnMatrix.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

            bulImageStatus = FALSE;

            [btnMatrix addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [btnMatrix setBackgroundImage:imgDefaultBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [viewWithButtons addSubview:btnMatrix];

            [arrButton addObject:btnMatrix];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"arrButton object count is:--> %d",[arrButton count]);
        [self.view addSubview:viewWithButtons];
}

-(void)AddImageToArray
{

    arr_FirstSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *strImageName;

if(appDelegate.intCategoryBtnTag == 0)
{
    for (intimg = 1; intimg <= 28; intimg++)
    {
        strImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_1.png",intimg];
        NSLog(@"strImageName is :--> %@",strImageName);
        [arr_FirstSet addObject:strImageName];
    }
    NSLog(@"arr_FirstSet objects are...%@",arr_FirstSet);
}
}

-(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *img;
    NSString *strImageName;
    strImageName = [arr_FirstSet objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [arr_FirstSet count]/2];
    NSLog(@"btnMatrix is:--> %@",strImageName);
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageName];
    //[btnMatrix setImage:img forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    NSLog(@"sender detail is:--> %@",sender);
    [sender setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

This is my code to set the dynamic buttons in "**setButtons_AsPerTheMatrixSelection**" method,

"**AddImageToArray**" method is used to add images from bundle to NSMutableArray (arr_FirstSet) one by one.

"**changeImage**" method is used to set the background of particular button.

I am able to set the images as background to the buttons randomly,

But the main problem is that i have to set fixed dynamic image to particular button.

right now on each click of particular button i am getting changed random image when i press it once, twice, thrice etc...

I have to set any particular image which is generated randomly in the "changeImage" to single button & rest to the other buttons single-single.

Then i have to check if two buttons have same background then these two buttons will be removed from the matrix.

Please guide me for the mistake i am doing & help me.

Comment: [sender setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [sender setEnabled:FALSE];
now that image is not changed...if i wrote both lines....but it should gone if match image is not found....

Comment: Update     :       [sender setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateDisabled];  You can see that image but in disable state.

Comment: is there any way to generate random but even set of images, ( like "1_1.png" ) in the function it should be 2,4,6 etc....set to the buttons...?

Comment: You mean you don't want to set one image twice in a button?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Please replace this method

    -(void)changeImage:(UIButton *)sender   
    {    
            UIImage *img;    
            NSString *strImageName;
            strImageName = [arr_FirstSet objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [arr_FirstSet count]/2];    

            img = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageName];   

    //for the first time sender.imageView.image property will be null then only we set image to the button. 
//For second click this condition fails and does not set the other image.
            if(!sender.imageView.image)   
            {
                [sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [sender setImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            }
// Calling a method to check if two images of buttons are same.
            [self checkIfTwoImagesAreSame:sender];
    }

    //And Add this method

    - (void)checkIfTwoImagesAreSameImageMaching:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        for(UIView *subview in [viewWithButtons subviews])
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subview;
// This condition is comparing clicked button image with all the buttons images of the viewWithButtons view if it isEqual: 
                if(sender.imageView.image && btn.imageView.image && [sender.imageView.image isEqual:btn.imageView.image])
                {
// this is checking if the clicked button is not comparing with itself
                    if(btn.tag != sender.tag)
                    {
                        [btn removeFromSuperview];
                        [sender removeFromSuperview];
    //                    OR
    //                    btn.selected = YES;
    //                    sender.selected = YES;
    //                    OR                    
    //                    btn.hidden = YES;
    //                    sender.hidden = YES;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.